# evaluation of a command in variable for prerequisite of makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a Makefile and I encounter some problems. I have a command which returns a string on stdout and I want to store this string in a variable. This program returns the list of dependencies of a file and I want to inject this list into the prerequisite line.

For now, I have this:

```
FILE= $(eval cut -d '.' -f1 $@)
FILEDEP= ./listfiledepend  $(FILE).bar
IMAGEDEP= ./listimgdepend  $(FILE).bar

%.foo: %.bar $(eval $(FILEDEP)
       Some code to do

%.pdf: %.foo $(eval $(IMAGEDEP))
       Some code to do
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why.
I don't know how to do that

Comment: Read [8.9 The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html)
and [8.13 The shell Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)